# Can't archive my Xamarin Android project anymore after latest update Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, archive

I just updatet my Visual Studio and I can't archive my Xamarin Android project anymore. Is de option moved to somewhere else? First it was above "View Archive" when you right-click on the Android project, but it disappeard.

Someone know where it moved or what I have to do to archive my project again?

Comment: I can't believe it but just after I post this question the option was back again. I was looking for the option again but was in my iOS project and found it onder the Builds options. I clicked it and saw it was my iOS project. Changed it to Android, and the option was back. Maybe this helps someone else who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe it but just after I post this question the option was back again. I was looking for the option again but was in my iOS project and found it onder the Builds options. I clicked it and saw it was my iOS project. Changed it to Android, and the option was back. Maybe this helps someone else who has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio was the solution for me